# Displaying all Custom fields on post except some

Tags: customization, labels

I have been trying to display all my custom fields listed like this on my page:

```
Label1: Value1
Label2: Vaule2
```

and so on.

But I only interessed the the label - I have this code:

```
<h3>All Post Meta</h3>

<?php $getPostCustom=get_post_custom(); // Get all the data ?>

<?php
foreach($getPostCustom as $name=>$value) {

    echo "<strong>".$name."</strong>"."  =>  ";

    foreach($value as $nameAr=>$valueAr) {
            echo "<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
            echo $nameAr."  =>  ";
            echo var_dump($valueAr);
    }

    echo "<br /><br />";

} ?>
```

But it comes up like this:

All Post Meta

```
_edit_lock => 
     0 => string(12) "1462734482:1" 

_edit_last => 
     0 => string(1) "1" 

wpcf-brugernavn => 
     0 => string(10) "Kim Domino" 

wpcf-afdeling => 
     0 => string(6) "Lemvig"
```

I want to show all but the "`edit_last`" "`edit_lock`" because that does not make any sense to my homepage. So I wanna have the list like this:

```
Brugernavn: Kim Domino

Afdeling: Lemvig
```

Comment: What is `wpcf-`? Is that some custom prefix you set? Also, please mind your Markup and fix if needed.

Comment: What do you mean by Markup? I think that wpcf_ comes from WordPress CustomFields... I have installed "Types" to make the Custom Fields with.

Comment: Please read [ask] to see how this site is meant to work. A link to your site will never be needed. In fact, outgoing links are just meant to be there to help explaining something in depth that is already in a question or answer. With "Markup" I mean formatting (code for example should not be wrapped in a blockquote). I fixed that for you, it's meant as guide for future questions.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to walk/map/filter the array before printing them. There're plenty of `array_*()` functions provided by PHP for that. Example:

```
$custom = get_post_custom();

// Remove all strings starting with `_`
array_filter( $custom, function( $data, $name ) {
    return "_" !== substr( $name, 0, 1 );
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH );

foreach ( $custom as $field )
    var_dump( $field );
```

Comment: Ok sorry... all new in here, and not that good with PHP coding... you say that I have to filter the array BEFORE printing them... but I do that AFTER i `code`
<?php $getPostCustom=get_post_custom(); // Get all the data ?>
`/code`

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work with my current code, comes up with "Missing argument 2 for {closure}()"

Comment: I got it to work ONLY with my Custom Fields, but I still need to remove the wpcf-

Comment: Fixed that error, it was just the wrong second argument.